# Add index to ORACLE SQL results to make results unique

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table that lists group IDs (1 to 6) and the name of the related tool (say A and B) and the users in each group. Like this:

```
User ID | Group ID | Tool Name |
User1   | 1        | A         |
User2   | 2        | A         |
User3   | 3        | A         |
User4   | 4        | B         |
User5   | 5        | B         |
User6   | 6        | B         |
User7   | 1        | A         |
User8   | 2        | A         |
User9   | 3        | A         |
User10  | 4        | B         |
User11  | 5        | B         |
User12  | 6        | B         |
...
User999 | 6        | B         |
```

*Edited for clarity

The different groups represent different levels of access within the same tool. I'd like to query the table to get simply the list of groups and tools, but making the tool names "unique" and representing the access level. So the result should be like so:

```
Group ID | Tool Name |
1        | A1        |
2        | A2        |
3        | A3        |
4        | B1        |
5        | B2        |
6        | B3        |
```

Any ideas? I tried sticking the group ID after the tool name, but that's not as readable. Any help would be appreciated?

Answer (score 0):

Use `row_number()`:

```
select t.*, tool || row_number() over (partition by tool order by userid)
from t;
```

Comment: Thank you! 
Unfortunately this does not stop counting rows. I might have misled, but the table is much, much longer than just 6 rows. There are hundreds of users, currently 6 different tools and each tool has 3 user groups. When I tried the above, I got all the way up to B1020. Each tool has only 3 different levels of access. Except for some that only have 1 or 2.